# Updating an existing value in php

Tags: php, sql

I'm inserting some values into my database, which is working successfully. However when i insert a new value for an id that has a previous value, the old val isn't replaced by the new, instead they're kept both. I'm trying to update the function with an if/else statement (commented part). But still the same result.

```
 $options = '';
    $filter=mysql_query("select afnumber from employees WHERE Status='Employed '");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($filter)) {
        $options .="<option >" . $row['afnumber'] . "</option>";
    }
    $menu="<form id='filter' name='filter' method='post' action=''>
    AFNumber : <select name='SelectAF' id='filter' style='color:grey;'>" . $options . "</select>
    Added hours: <input type='text' name='AddedHours' style=' padding: 10px;border: solid 2px #c9c9c9; width:50px; height:2px;'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' style='width:80px; height:30px; text-align:center; padding:0px;'>
    </form>
    <br>
    ";

   /* if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            $addedhours = $_POST['AddedHours'];
            $selectaf = $_POST['SelectAF'];
        if($addedhours == ""){
                  $sql="INSERT INTO `editedworkhours` (`AFNumber`,`AddedWH`) VALUES('$selectaf','$addedhours')";

                 $getResult =mysql_query($sql);

        }
        else{

                    $sql2 = "UPDATE editedworkhours SET AddedWH=$addedhours WHERE AFNumber=$selectaf";
                   $getResult =mysql_query($sql2);
        }
        } 

    echo $menu; */



    echo '<div class="scrolldiv">';

         try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=hr', 'root', 'J546');
        $conn->exec("set names utf8");
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
        $num_rows = $conn->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees')->fetchColumn(); 
        $pages = new Paginator($num_rows,9,array(15,3,6,9,12,25,50,100,250,'All'));
        echo $pages->display_pages();
        echo "<span class=\"\">".$pages->display_jump_menu().$pages->display_items_per_page()."</span>";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT employees.afnumber,employees.name,employees.dateofemployment,employees.actualpost,employees.department FROM employees WHERE employees.status='Employed' AND (employees.afnumber LIKE '%$search%' OR employees.name LIKE '%$search%') ORDER BY employees.afnumber DESC LIMIT :start,:end");
        $stmt->bindParam(':start', $pages->limit_start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':end', $pages->limit_end, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        $ewhtable = "<table class='sortable'><tr><th>AFNumber</th><th>Employee Name</th><th>Years of Service</th><th>Actual Post</th><th>Department</th><th>Added Hours</th></tr>\n";
        foreach($result as $row) {
            $years=explode("/", $row[2]);
            $years[2]=intval(date ('Y')) - $years[2];

    $sql="SELECT addedwh FROM editedworkhours WHERE afnumber='$row[0]'";
    $var = "";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result2 = $stmt->fetchAll();

    foreach ($result2 AS $row2) {
      $var .= $row2['addedwh'] . "\n";
    }

            $ewhtable .= "<tr><td>$row[0]</td><td>$row[1]</td><td>$years[2]</td><td>$row[3]</td><td>$row[4]</td><td>$var</td></tr>\n";
        }
        $ewhtable .= "</table>\n";
        echo $ewhtable;
        exportTable(str_replace("&","",$ewhtable),"EmployeeWorkingHoursTable");
        echo $pages->display_pages();
        echo "<p class=\"paginate\">Page: $pages->current_page of $pages->num_pages</p>\n";
        echo "</div>";
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you ask. An `INSERT` statement can _never_ update a row, it will always insert a new value or fail. An UPDATE statement certainly will _never_ insert a new row. You might want to take a loko into the mysql documentation for the feature `INSERT OR UPDATE IF NOT EXISTS`...

Comment: @arkascha what should i do to update an existing value?

Comment: If you want to updated, then you use an `UPDATE` statement. As said: that will certainly never insert a new row. There must be some other issue with your code. Maybe `$_POST['AddedHours']` is set, but contains an empty string? You will have to debug that, we cannot do that for you. Dump the values or use a debugger to step through the code.

Comment: @arkascha is this alternate solution more suitable? http://jsfiddle.net/cdyg0avn/

Comment: No idea what "alternate solution" you refer to. One question: I suggested above that you take a look at the mysql documentation and the `IF NOT EXISTS` feature. Did you do that? _Why not?_

Comment: @arkascha ok i'll check it out. Sorry, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

If AddedHours input value has only a space, your comparison `if($addedhours == "")` will fail.

Always `trim` the values before comparison.

```
$addedhours = trim($_POST['AddedHours']);
```